# React.js I can't get rid of the loader icon

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm developing a Movie App. I dont have problem about receiving data and viewing it on the screen. But when i want to add a Loader to my project. It never goes away instead of staying for 1-2 seconds.

```js
const Movies = () => {
  const { movies, isLoading } = useGlobalContext();
  if (isLoading) {
    return <div className="loading"></div>;
  }
  return (
    <section className="movies">
      {movies.map((movie) => {
        const {
          imdbID: key,
          Poster: poster,
          Title: title,
          Year,
          year,
        } = movie;

        return (
          <Link to={`/movies/${key}`} key={key} className="movie">
            <article>
              <img src={poster} alt={title} />
              <div className="movie-info">
                <h4 className="title">{title}</h4>
                <p>{year}</p>
              </div>
            </article>
          </Link>
        );
      })}
    </section>
  );
};
```

It's my context page `useGlobalContext` and `isLoading` coming from here

```js
const AppContext = React.createContext();

const AppProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [isError, setError] = useState({ show: false, msg: "" });
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("spider-man");

  const fetchMovies = async (url) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const data = await response.json();
      if (data.Response === "True") {
        setMovies(data.Search);
        setError({ show: false, msg: "" });
      } else {
        setError({ show: true, msg: data.Error });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchMovies(`${API_ENDPOINT}&s=${query}`);
  }, []);
  return (
    <AppContext.Provider
      value={{ isLoading, isError, movies, query, setQuery }}
    >
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};
export const useGlobalContext = () => {
  return useContext(AppContext);
};

export { AppContext, AppProvider };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never set your `isLoading` state back to `false` after you loaded your assets

```
const AppProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [isError, setError] = useState({ show: false, msg: "" });
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("spider-man");

  const fetchMovies = async (url) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const data = await response.json();
      if (data.Response === "True") {
        setMovies(data.Search);
        setError({ show: false, msg: "" });
      } else {
        setError({ show: true, msg: data.Error });
      }
      setIsLoading(false); // <--- added this bit
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      setIsLoading(false); // <--- added this bit
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchMovies(`${API_ENDPOINT}&s=${query}`);
  }, []);
  return (
    <AppContext.Provider
      value={{ isLoading, isError, movies, query, setQuery }}
    >
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};
```